# How to render a different controller / action from within an action in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is possible but I want to render a controller / action in response to a different action like in my `routes.rb`, I have:

```
get ':handle' => 'handler#index'
```

and in `handler_controller`, I have:

```
  def index
    handle=Handle.where('handle=?',params[:handle]).first
    if handle.handle_type=='Location'
       # call location / show  with id from handle
    else
      render text: "not found"
    end  
  end
```

How would I do this? I should mention, I don't want to do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
def action_that_calls_one_from_another_controller
  controller_you_want = ControllerYouWant.new
  controller_you_want.request = request
  controller_you_want.response = response
  controller_you_want.action_you_want
end
```

Comment: This will not execute `before_filter`s and all such stuff, may do, but is not a generic solution

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using an "internal redirect" approach.

Inside rails this can be done via middleware that calls `@app` again and tracks redirect loops. See tutorial [here](http://lukas.dolezalu.cz/2014/01/18/ruby-on-rails-internal-redirect-and-render-of-action-from-another-controller/)

Also can be done by utilizing nginx's `X-Accel-Redirect`: make a regular routes for referenced resources, but instead of regular redirect issue a `X-Accel-Redirect` header, for user it will be like your page rendered without redirect.

Comment: hmm.... I get that - a bit surprised this isn't natively supported. It might just be easier to duplicate the code from the intended controller rather than go into middleware.

Comment: @timpone code duplication is always a smell, at least make it a module

Comment: I hear you - but the duplication is literally two lines. A bit surprised this isn't natively supported in controllers to be honest.